# Given 3 dicts of varying size, how would I find the intersections and values?

Tags: python, dictionary

I looked up intersections of dictionaries, and tried to use the set library, but couldn't figure out how to show the values and not just pull out the keys to work with them, so I'm hoping for some help. I've got three dictionaries of random length:

```
dict_a= {1: 488, 2: 336, 3: 315, 4: 291, 5: 275}

dict_b={2: 0, 3: 33, 1: 61, 5: 90, 15: 58}

dict_c= {1: 1.15, 9: 0, 2: 0.11, 15: 0.86, 19: 0.008, 20: 1834}
```

I need to figure out what keys are in dictionary A, B, and C, and combine those to a new dictionary. Then I need to figure out what keys are in dictionary A&B or A&C or B&C, and pull those out to a new dictionary. What I should have left over in A, B, and C are the ones that are unique to that dictionary.

So, eventually, I'd wind up with separate dictionaries, as follows:

```
total_intersect= {1: {488, 61, 1.15}, 2: {336, 0, 0.11}}
A&B_only_intersect = {3: {315,33}, 5:{275,90}} (then dicts for A&C intersect and B&C intersect)
dict_a_leftover= {4:291} (and dicts for leftovers from B and C)
```

I thought about using zip, but it's important that all those values stay in their respective places, meaning I can't have A values in the C position. Any help would be awesome!

Comment: To see which keys appear in all thre just do: `common_keys = dict_a.keys() & dict_b.keys() & dict_c.keys()` (if using python2 replace `.keys()` with `.viewkeys()`). Then try to come up with a way to build the combined dictionary.

Comment: Which version of Python?  View objects will probably do what you need, but the syntax is different between 2 and 3.

Comment: _"I can't have A values in the C position"_ You're using dicts and sets, both of which are unordered. What's this "position" you speak of?

Comment: I think he wants lists as values in the resulting dicts instead of sets as he wrote it by mistake.

Comment: Sorry @Rawing, basically what I mean is that if I were to add up all three dictionaries, I'd have 1: with 3 values, but 3: with only two values. Eventually, this is all going into an Excel spreadsheet, so A would need to all line up, B would need to line up, et cetera.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   lst =  [dict_a,dict_b,dict_c] 
   total_intersect_key = set(dict_a) & set(dict_b) & set(dict_c)
   total_intersect = { k:[ item[k] for item in lst ]  for k in total_intersect_key}
```

output:

```
{1: [488, 61, 1.15], 2: [336, 0, 0.11]}
```

for other question just reduce the lst elements

```
lst = [dict_a,dict_b]
A&B_only_intersect = { k:[ item[k] for item in lst ]  for k in set(dict_a.keys) & set(dict_b)}
```

also you can convert it to a function

```
def intersect(lst):
     return { k:[ item[k] for item in lst if k in item ]  for k in reduce( lambda x,y:set(x)&set(y), lst ) }
```

example:

```
>>> a
{1: 488, 2: 336, 3: 315, 4: 291, 5: 275}
>>> b
{1: 61, 2: 0, 3: 33, 5: 90, 15: 58}
>>> c
{1: 1.15, 2: 0.11, 9: 0, 15: 0.86, 19: 0.008, 20: 1834}
>>> intersect( [a,b] )
{1: [488, 61], 2: [336, 0], 3: [315, 33], 5: [275, 90]}
>>> intersect( [a,c] )
{1: [488, 1.15], 2: [336, 0.11]}
>>> intersect( [b,c] )
{1: [61, 1.15], 2: [0, 0.11], 15: [58, 0.86]}
>>> intersect( [a,b,c] )
{1: [488, 61, 1.15], 2: [336, 0, 0.11]}
```

-----update-----

```
def func( lst, intersection):
     if intersection:
         return { k:[ item[k] for item in lst if k in item ]  for k in reduce( lambda x,y:set(x)&set(y), lst ) }
     else:
         return { k:[ item[k] for item in lst if k in item ]  for k in reduce(lambda x,y:set(x).difference(set(y)), lst ) }

>>> func([a,c],False)
{3: [315], 4: [291], 5: [275]}
>>> func([a,b],False)
{4: [291]}
>>> func( [func([a,b],False),func([a,c],False)],True)
{4: [[291], [291]]}
```

One issue: you need to take the duplication out for final result or try to improve func itself.

```
{k:set( reduce( lambda x,y:x+y, v) ) for k,v in func( [func([a,b],False),func([a,c],False)],True).iteritems()}

{4: set([291])}
```

Comment: Wow, the function example is super elegant, thank you!

Comment: @user3097421  not a problem.

Comment: So then, if I wanted to find people who are just on A, but not B or C, should I find all the intersects first, and then do some sort of set math?

Comment: I don't really understand the update. Am I now saying, for intersect a,b that I want the ones that do not intersect A and B? I'd need to keep it separate, so I need the a's that are left over, the b's that are left over, and the c's that are left over.

Comment: @user3097421 so what you want is a&~(b|c)?. the new update is first find difference between a and b, then difference between a and c.at end,find intersection between first part results. The new parameter give you ability to do the difference or intersection.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this might help

```
dict_a= {1: 488, 2: 336, 3: 315, 4: 291, 5: 275}
a = set(dict_a)
dict_b={2: 0, 3: 33, 1: 61, 5: 90, 15: 58}
b =  set( dict_b)
dict_c= {1: 1.15, 9: 0, 2: 0.11, 15: 0.86, 19: 0.008, 20: 1834}
c = set( dict_c )

a_intersect_b = a & b 

a_intersect_c = a & c

b_intersect_c = b & c

a_interset_b_intersect_c = a_intersect_b & c


total_intersect = {}  
for id in a_interset_b_intersect_c:
    total_intersect[id] = { dict_a[id] , dict_b[id] , dict_c[id] }

print total_intersect


a_b_only_intersect = {}
for id in a_intersect_b:
    a_b_only_intersect[id] =  { dict_a[id] , dict_b[id] }

print a_b_only_intersect

b_c_only_intersect = {}
for id in b_intersect_c:
    b_c_only_intersect[id] =  { dict_b[id] , dict_c[id] }

print b_c_only_intersect

a_c_only_intersect = {}
for id in a_intersect_c:
    a_c_only_intersect[id] =  { dict_a[id] , dict_c[id] }

print a_c_only_intersect
```

Similarly u can find leftovers in a , b  and c using "difference" of sets.